# Recovering the connected component of the identity in a Lie group from its Lie connected subgroups of dimension 1

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a non-discrete Lie group. Can the connected component of its identity ($G_e$) be presented as the union of its Lie connected subgroups of dimension 1: $$G_e = \bigcup\{ \text{Lie connected subgroups of } G \text{ of dimension } 1 \}?$$

Comment: No. 1 dimensional connected subgroups can be shown to be 1-parameter subgroups. So they must be in the image of $\exp$ and that is not surjective in general.

Comment: @Callum What about those isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: What about them? They are still 1parameter subgroups.

Comment: @Callum Oh, I didn't know that they are also 1-parameter groups.